# Session variables values NOT available accross web pages in WebMatrix

Tags: session-variables, webmatrix

I would like to use `session variables` throughout my WebMatrix web pages.

For an unknown reason, they are `not available accross the pages` (only to the page where they are defined).

**In my login page, code section**:

```
if (WebSecurity.Login(userName, password, rememberMe)) {

    // Session variable holding the UserType

    var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
    var userTypeData = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Name FROM UserTypes INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON UserProfiles.UserTypeId = UserTypes.UserTypeId WHERE UserId = @0",WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
    Session ["UserType"] = userTypeData.Name;

    // Eventual redirection to the previous URL

    var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

    if (returnUrl.IsEmpty()) {
        Response.Redirect("~/auth/authenticated");
    }
    else {
        Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
    }
```

I get here a `"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"` hence if there is always a UserType. THis is the fist problem.

In the "authenticated" page where I'm redirected, if I use exactly the same query and session variable definition, I can display it as :

```
You are a user of type: @Session["UserType"] -> HTML section
```

**On other pages**, I'm trying to ´display or hidden (update) buttons` through the session variable.

```
 @if (Session["UserType"]=="here the variable value; a string") {
                <a class="linkbutton" href="condoedit?condoId=@condoData.CondoId">Update</a>    
 }
```

Button is never displayed as the `session variable appears to be empty` !!

Comment: try this way @{ var newObj = Session["UserType"]; } and then if condition check.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to test if there are problems with the query (BTW, use QueryValue instead of QuerySingle if you need only the user name).

Try something like

```
var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
var userTypeData = db.QueryValue("SELECT Name FROM UserTypes INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON UserProfiles.UserTypeId = UserTypes.UserTypeId WHERE UserId = @0",WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userTypeData)) {
    Session["UserType"] = "IsEmpty";
} else {
    Session["UserType"] = userTypeData;
}
```

and test on other pages if the session variable value is "IsEmpty".

**Edit**

In the other pages convert to string the session variable value and store it into a local variable

```
var uType = Session["UserType"].ToString();
```

Comment: Try reading the session variable value with `Session["UserType"].ToString()` instead of `Session["UserType"]`.

Comment: The value is displayed on other pages if I take it out of the IF condition -> @Session[UserType] alone works. We at least know where the problem is ! The session variable is an object (result of SQL query) and the if condition tests on a string. Maybe some casting here needed ?

Comment: Yep. This is it. Please edit your solution and I will accept it. By the way, I still have some other unanswered questions. If you have some spare time ;-)

Comment: I'm back again. For a few minutes I got the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Line 109:                @if (Session["UserType"].ToString()=="Syndic") { button link }. I logged out and logged in again and it seems to have disappeared. But for how long ... ? Any idea on how to prevent this ? Declare another variable on each page to hold the session variable's value ?

Answer (score 0):

When the item is stored in session, it is stored as an object data type, so it will need to be cast back to its original data type if there is no implicit cast between object and the original type. ([mikesdotnetting.com](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages))

-> Session["UserType"]`.ToString()`

```
@if (Session["UserType"].ToString()=="here the variable value; a string") {
            <a class="linkbutton" href="condoedit?condoId=@condoData.CondoId">Update</a>
```

}